# How to make my iphone app work on an iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

It is my understanding (i have seen it) that some apps can be opened and viewed in an iPad.  Although, the iPad keeps the screen small, or pixelated if doubled the screen size.

I am attempting to do the same thing with my app, however when I attempt to run it on an iPad it crashes with the error

'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPad'

This is obvious, as I do no have a storyboard for the iPad, but currently I don't want one.  I just want the iPad to run the app as an iPhone app in a smaller version.  So my question is, how do I stop it from looking for the iPad storyboard?  Its my understanding I must adjust something in the plist.info but I don't know how to access that in xcode. its my understanding you select the project in the navigator then select 'info' but I don't see any information that people say should be in the plist.info.

Thanks

Comment: Open your target's Summary tab and check the Devices field.

Comment: @ilmiacs i have set it to iphone but i still get the same crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made your application universal. You want to set your "devices" to iPhone. This can be done on the target summary page (No need to interact with your .plist directly).

[image]

Comment: this, at first, seemed to be exactly what i needed.  but i still get that weird crash about the missing MainStoryboard_iPad

Comment: @JesseDurham Sometimes when Xcode gets an error in its head it really sticks with it. Try deleting the application from the iPad(The file on the device might not have been updated.) and cleaning the target. And perhaps restarting Xcode.

Comment: i deleted the app, cleaned, rebuilt, restarted xcode (in that order) and the error is still there.  The weird part is I actually DO have a blank MainStoryboard_iPad file in my project that was created when I very first created the project for possible future iPad compatibility.

Comment: @JesseDurham In that case try simply deleting or renaming that file. Also check your application's *-info.plist for a key named `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad` if it's there remove it. Also check your AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching.. method for any auto-generated logic to launch an iPad storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Only target iPhone platform, and do not call any iPad interface objects in your code. You should look in your Main xib file to make sure there are no references to an iPad interface object.

iPhone only apps should natively run in double-pixel mode. In order to resolve the pixelated / grainy issue you see, use @2x (for iPhone) size images. This will reduce the pixelation you see, but will still contain some.

Comment: I'm not using xib.  I'm using story boards as introduce in xcode 4.3 i believe.  I also have done nothing to adhere to anything iPad related to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the final issue.  After editing the summary to 'iPhone'  I also had to go into the Info tab and change the line that says

'Main storyboard file base name (iPad) to MainStoryboard_iPhone.  It was currently set to MainStoryboard_iPad.  That second step fixed the issue.

Thanks guys!